# Can't add Attributes to channel in Twilio Programmable chat?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, twilio-api

Twilio document says Attributes are "The developer-defined extensible attributes for this channel". But When i try to add attribute. I got Error #50107, IP Messaging: User not authorized for command.

How to add attribute not based on user role?

```
[channel setAttributes:dictionary completion:^(TCHResult *result){
if (result.isSuccessful) {
    NSLog(@"Success");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"%d", result.resultCode);
}
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Setting properties on channels, including channel attributes, is protected by the [chat permissions model](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/permissions). Users with the role of Channel Admin or Service Admin are allowed to update channel attributes, but not regular users.

If you need to allow all users to set channel attributes, but you don't want to make them Channel Admins, then you could create a route in your web application (I guess you have one that generates access tokens) that uses the [Chat REST API to update the Channel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/channels). That way you can retain control over the permissions, but still allow for regular users to update attributes.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. for now i just make all users Channel Admin.

Comment: That is a temporary measure at best! It would also give your users all the ability to delete all channels they are admin of.

Comment: @MandalTsas How to set all users to Channel Admin?